# Error with passing data between m files

Tags: objective-c

I have two .m files and trying to pass data between them

I have a function like this

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemsFromFile:(unsigned int)file number;
```

in the second .m file I am not able to access this function.

but if I remove the function argument, then this function visible in the second .m file.

i.e. if I change to

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemsFromFile;
```

then this function is visible

Can you shed some light on this?

More details

first file .h declaration

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemFromFile:(unsigned int)file number;
```

first file Brain.m definition

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemFromFile:(unsigned int)filenumber
{
    return 1;
}
```

second file .m

I am creating an object and calling the function

```
 self.myTestObject = [Brain alloc];
 [myTestObject brainInit];

 count = myTestObject.ReadNumberOfItemFromFile:1; 
 // gives me an error that "property not found on the object
```

As mentioned above if I remove the argument from function definition and declaration and then try to call the function with out the argument, there is not error.

Comment: Post the code for the 2 .m files as well as their .h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a typo in what you posted,

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemsFromFile:(unsigned int)file number;
```

will not work because you have a space between file and number.

The compiler should generate an error when you put this in a .h file.  If you're not getting an error (and are able to run your program), then what is actually in your .h file is something other than what you posted.

More likely is that the method declaration in the .h file and the method name in the .m file are not EXACTLY the same.  If they're not, the compiler should give you a warning about a missing method definition.

Edit:

Looking now at your posted code, your line:

```
count = myTestObject.ReadNumberOfItemFromFile:1;
```

Should be:

```
count = [myTestObject ReadNumberOfItemFromFile:1];
```

Comment: sorry. the space in the argument was a typo.

Comment: the declaration and definition are EXACTLY same. still no luck

Comment: Thank you. That solved the compilation issue. But there is something wrong which I still trying to figure out.  When I put a brake point, its not jumping inside that method. So the count is always returning 0. May be some initialization issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your line:

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemsFromFile:(unsigned int)file number;
```

shouldn't work. It should read something like:

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemsFromFile:(unsigned int)fileNumber;
```

---

Basically, make sure that in both .h files the method signature is **exactly the same**. It sounds possible that in one header file you have:

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemsFromFile:(unsigned int)fileNumber;
```

and in the other you have:

```
- (unsigned int)ReadNumberOfItemsFromFile;
```

Comment: no, i made sure the declaration and definition is same. Still no luck. The moment I remove the argument, it becomes visible. Looks strange!

Comment: Could you copy and paste the method signature exactly as it appears in the code? I'll see if I can sort it for you.